# jQuery how to get innerWidth but without the padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From the docs, innerWidth does almost what I need:

> "Gets the inner width (excludes the border and includes the padding)
>   for the first matched element."

I need to know the width *excluding* the padding. I.e. the usable space inside the element.

Does jquery provide anything like this - done a bit of googling and can't find any solutions.

I thought about getting the `padding-left` and `padding-right` values to subtract from inner width- But given these could be percentages, pixels or em I'm not sure if this would be reliable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)?

Answer (score 74):

You're probably just looking for the width() function..

See the docs, it excludes the padding: http://api.jquery.com/width/

(Just as intended in modern browser's representation of the css width property)

**Edit:** It's now 2012 and jQuery 1.8 is just coming out. While this is still relevant, you may also want to read the [following article from the jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/) regarding `box-sizing` considerations in version 1.8

Comment: Nowadays it's so confusing, because padding increased the width and height of boxes in the earlier stages of html. So innerWidth or innerHeight calculates the width and height without padding. Now everyone uses box-sizing and padding shrinks the available space, by keeping the width as is.

Answer (score 21):

```
$('#element').width();
```

It's as simple as that!