# Is there a way to determine height and width of the video-margins inside an embed-responsive video element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to get info from inside the embed responsive element.

Embed-responsive video elements automatically add internal margins on the x or y axis to keep a video aspect preserved. We used to call these 'letterboxes' back in the beginning of 16x9 days. how can i find the size of these internal margins/letterboxes?

I've done my due diligence and cannot find anything online or stack overflow.

I am working on a large Angular 7 project and don't have any code to paste since this question is somewhat theoretical.

looking for a real front end guru to help me here.

thanks!

Comment: did you try to check for jquery method with width / innerWidth/outerWidth ?

Comment: @MaxiGui checking now, we do have a jquery package added, if i find anything good ill let you know so u can answer the question and get credit.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_innerwidth.asp according to W3 docs, this method gives u the element and padding width, i am looking for a measurement inside of the element itself. how much of the actual element (no padding/border/margin/positioning) is letterbox and how much is video.

Comment: if your final goal is to maintain video ratio, this article may help: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/

Comment: sorry @MaxiGui, my video ratio is being maintained perfectly, i need to determine the size of the letterboxes INTERNALLY on the element. thanks for your help partner

Comment: Then you want the width as I said in my first comment: [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/width/) and here the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567915/jquery-how-to-get-innerwidth-but-without-the-padding/7567981 As the .width does not include padding in its calculation

Comment: incorrect. i want the letterbox width or height inside the embed responsive element.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having the video in a large container and handling its own embed responsive letterboxes, i put it in another intermediate container and used calc in css to determine the height and force the intermediate container to a perfect aspect ratio. i still have the embed responsive effect but no letterboxing. now if i add a label or overlay, it stays the exact size of the video.

```
height: calc((100%*3) /4);
```